# showing the result of multiply two input value in a div called result

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I just want to show the result in this div ,i tried to use nodeValue instead value and call the finalCalc fun in js file but it show nothing when i click on the button.

```js
var billValue=document.getElementById("dollars").value,
 peopleValue=document.getElementById("people").value,
 theResult=document.getElementById("result"),
 calculateButton=document.getElementById("calculateButton");


function calculateTip(x,y){
    var reso=x*y;
  theResult.innerHTML=reso;
}

 function finalCalc() {
    calculateTip(billValue,peopleValue);
}
```

```html
<form>
<label>how much was your bill?</label>
             <label for ="dollars">$</label>
             <input value ="0" type="text" id="dollars" placeholder="Bill Amount ">
<br>
 <label for="people">How many people are sharing the bill?</label>
             <input value ="0" type="text" id="people">
            <button type="button" id="calculateButton" onclick()="finalCalc()">CALCULATE</button>
            <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to set the variables in the function. You're setting them before the user fills in the inputs.

Comment: Also `onclick()=` should be `onclick=`

Answer (score 0):

onClick is written as onClick="" instead of onclick()="", reworked your code a little, hope this helps.

```js
var billValue = document.getElementById("dollars").value,
    peopleValue = document.getElementById("people").value,
    theResult = document.getElementById("result"),
    calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculateButton");


function calculateTip(x, y) {
    return x * y;
}

function finalCalc() {
    theResult.innerHTML = calculateTip(billValue, peopleValue);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="calculateButton" onClick="finalCalc()">CALCULATE</button>
```